# Loading data into mysql ignore first line

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to load some data from a text file into mysql. I would like to ignore the first line.

From the mysql 5.5 manual, there is a "ignore 1 line" option.

I have tried using this query to no avail:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'iso-languagecodes.txt' INTO TABLE iso_languagecodes (iso_639_3, iso_639_2, iso_639_1, language_name) IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong?

This is the error I am receiving

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' IGNO
RE 1 LINES' at line 1
```

The following 2 queries will work:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'iso-languagecodes.txt' INTO TABLE iso_languagecodes (iso_639_3, iso_639_2, iso_639_1, language_name);
```

or

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'iso-languagecodes.txt' INTO TABLE iso_languagecodes IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But, I need to be able to specify the columns and ignore the first line.

Comment: "...to no avail" -- what's the problem? Does the query run? Does it import the records? Does it import the first line?

Comment: Don't you/Shouldn't you specify how are the those lines delimited? For example by adding  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested, here is the final solution:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'iso-languagecodes.txt' INTO TABLE iso_languagecodes IGNORE 1 LINES (iso_639_3, iso_639_2, iso_639_1, language_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'iso-languagecodes.txt' INTO TABLE iso_languagecodes (iso_639_3, iso_639_2, iso_639_1, language_name)  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Replace the ',' for whatever delimiter you are using in your file; use '\t' for tabs

Comment: I am still getting an error with this method: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELD
S TERMINATED BY '\t'  IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1

Comment: @phpdev If you copied and pasted the error message verbatim from your mysql console, notice how there's an extra space in the word FIELD S. Did you type it correctly? It's supposed to be FIELDS, not FIELD S

Comment: Just double checked and the statement was typed in correctly, but am still gettign the error. Though I dont see why the delimiter is necessary when I was able to run queries without the delimiter.

Comment: I am not suggesting is required but if you don't specify it, it will assume the following defaults: FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''. Is that how your file is structured? If not, then you need to explicitly set those values.

Comment: Yes, the file is structured like that. I was able to load other files structured the same way into mysql, except for those files, there wasn't any first row of "labels" to ignore.

Comment: I just read your edit and I see that you have one working solution in which you specify your column names and you say you need that, if all is stopping you from using that approach is the fact that you need to skip the first line in the file, what's stopping you from writing a little script to remove that line from the file before running the MYSQL command?

Comment: Nothing really :P But I would like to get this method working. Having a separate script that deletes the first line feels very much like a hack to me.

Comment: If you have the time, by all means, figure out the issue, but if you are in a hurry, I would do this: sed -i -e '1d' your_original_file.txt > file_without_line1.txt // or perhaps pipe the output to MYSQL.